# Geography function over a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery, geography

I am trying to use the st_makeline() function in order to create lines for every points and the next one in a single column.
Do I need to create another column with the 2 points already ?

```
with t1 as(
SELECT *, ST_GEOGPOINT(cast(long as float64) , cast(lat as float64))  geometry FROM `my_table.faissal.trajets_flix` 
where id = 1
order by index_loc
)

select index_loc geometry
from t1
```

[Here are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5S2B.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: The tags "sql-server" and "google-bigquery" are (I think) mutually exclusive as they are different databases. Which one are you using? Based on the syntax, my guess is bigquery.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to want to write this code:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_makeline

```sql
WITH t1 as (
  SELECT *, ST_GEOGPOINT(cast(long as float64), cast(lat as float64)) geometry 
    FROM `my_table.faissal.trajets_flix` 
-- WHERE id = 1
)
SELECT id, ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(geometry ORDER BY index_loc)) traj 
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY id;
```

with output:

[image]

When visualized on the map.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below simple and cheap option

```
select st_geogfromtext(format('linestring(%s)', 
    string_agg(long || ' ' || lat order by index_loc))
  ) as path
from `my_table.faissal.trajets_flix`
where id = 1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

which is visualized as

[image]